# EOF when register but passed all check

Tags: openimaj

EOF when register but passed all check

I got EOF error when register, fixed after changing all 172 address to 127.0.0.1. Since I passed all check (both openim and chat), all components were started, and grep showed openim and chat are running, it should be able to register.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.